# Google Places place_changed listener not working on iPhone

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I'm using the autocomplete feature of Google Places.

Everything works fine on any browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari Mac): I start typing a street name, click on a result, the list of results closes and the event fires.

On Safari Mobile however, taping on a result does close the list of results, but the event never fires. This is on an iPhone 4S, iOS 9, but I had similar reports from users of other models as well.

My code, which uses a Google Map on the same page, is fairly standard:

```
<div id="map"></div>

<input type="text" name="location" id="location">

<script>
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            // ...
        );

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            document.getElementById('location'), {
                types: ['address'],
                componentRestrictions: {country: "re"}
            }
        );

        console.log('before listener');

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
            console.log('place changed');
        });

        console.log('after listener');
    }
</script>


<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&amp;callback=initMap&amp;language=fr-RE" async defer></script>
```

I connected the iPhone to the Mac, checked the web inspector, and I can see no error. I can see in the console the 'before listener' and 'after listener' messages logged, so the listener seems to be registered. But the 'place changed' message never appears when taping a result.

What can be the problem?

Comment: I suggest you provide a quick working fiddle so that this can be tested. Did you also check [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:Javascript3&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Introduced+Fixed+Summary+Internal+Stars&cells=tiles) for any similar issue that would already be reported? (I didn't check)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While trying to reproduce the bug in a fiddle as suggested by MrUpsidown, I discovered that this is [an outstanding issue with fastclick.js](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/pull/347).

I've disabled it for now.